# How to adjust the line spacing of the previous page？

Tags: widows-orphans, penalty

I'm working on an automatic mechanism for handling **orphans** and **widows** in my own defined documentclass.

Tex version: xelatex-2022

Current progress is to reference the widows-and-orphans package and override the corresponding method

Doubt:

1. When the widowpenalty is occurred/discovered ? Is after rendering ? Is predictable ?
2. Space of each paragraph in the previous page will be increased when i use original command `\widowpenalties`and then it worded. Does this phenomenon indicate that when the widowpenalty occurs, I can reduce the line spacing of the previous page and squeeze the widow line into the previous page?

Code:

```
\documentclass{book}
%\widowpenalties=4 10000 10000 10000 150  ===> In fact, only 1 row needs to be processed, but it is written as 4 for the sake of testing
\begin{document}
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\par
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\par
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\par
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\par
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\par
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\par
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\par
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\par
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\par
\end{document}
```

Qa1: Why adjust previous page spacing when widow row appears?

Ans1: I don't want overfull to appear when inserting a widow row to the previous page.

Qa2: Why `\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}`?

Ans2: I know this solution but not for my aiming.

Comment: you can not change the line spacing of any paragraph that has already been broken in to lines and added to the main vertical list (unless you use Lua from lualatex)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle if can't, how to explain phenomenon which each paragraph spacing increased when discovered widow line? How does it worked that pull down the paragraph witch the widow line belong to.

Comment: @Mahsatshak Line spacing usually refers to the space between lines _within_ a paragraph, which is pretty much fixed once the paragraph has been broken. What you are seeing is probably the paragraph spacing, which is the space between paragraphs and can be freely stretched. There's also some other spacing that can change like the space between a section heading and the following text.

Comment: That is \parskip (space between paragraphs) not baselineskip. Its value is not being changed either but it is stretchy so smaller or larger actual space on each page (not directly related to widow penalties) just as the space between words varies on each line on a paragraph

Comment: @MaxChernoff thanks, got it. So how do you change the previous page's spacings you mentioned? And how to control the scope of influence?

Comment: @Mahsatshak I'm not entirely sure what you're asking for, but you could try putting something like `\parskip=0pt plus 12pt` in your preamble (not that I'd endorse the results of that)

Comment: @MaxChernoff It means that a pagebreak has already occurred when \output penalty = \widowpenalty is detected. At this time, we set the current page as n, then the paragraph to which the widow line belongs starts at page n - 1. So how do ```\parskip=0pt plus 12pt``` only take effect on page n - 1 without affecting **parskip** on page n.

Comment: @Mahsatshak as I commented above you can not change the parskip above any paragraph that has been added, but as it is stretchy all paragraph spaces on a given page will stretch by the same amount to flush the last line to the bottom, just as word spaces stretch to ensure even left and right margins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question title asks about line spacing but the code suggests that you meant to ask about space between paragraphs, not between lines.

In your example, if the widowpenalties line is uncommented, more lines move to page 2 leaving page 1 underfull (not overfull, as your comment implies).

As by default in `book` class `\parskip` is stretchy all the inter paragraph spaces stretch so the new last line is placed at the bottom of the page.

The default value is `0.0pt plus 1.0pt` which is not enough stretch in this case, so you get

```
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [1
```

adding

```
 \setlength\parskip{0pt plus 3pt}
```

would be enough stretch here, but to ensure there is enough to get a line space even if there is only one paragraph break on the page, use

```
 \setlength\parskip{0pt plus \baselineskip}
```

so

```
\documentclass{book}
\widowpenalties=4 10000 10000 10000 150 % ===> In fact, only 1 row needs to be processed, but it is written as 4 for the sake of testing

\setlength\parskip{0pt plus \baselineskip}
\begin{document}
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\par
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\par
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\par
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\par
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\par
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\par
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\par
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\par
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\\
a text a text a text a text a text a text a text a text\par
\end{document}
```

Comment: thx, this answer have lot help for me. No matter [your comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/670529/how-to-adjust-the-line-spacing-of-the-previous-page#comment1666736_670529) explain that no solutions for my question, but i had a new idea to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

> When the widowpenalty is occurred/discovered ? Is after rendering ? Is predictable ?

`\widowpenalty` and `\clubpenalty` are usually set once in the preamble, although they can be freely changed at any point. When a page ends in a widow, the value of `\widowpenalty` is added to the page's `\outputpenalty`, and similarly for orphans/clubs.

As a general rule, you only want to set the values of `\widowpenalty` and `\clubpenalty` and read the value of `\outputpenalty`; reading `\widowpenalty` or setting `\outputpenalty` only makes sense very rarely.

For a longer description of how these values work, see [section 4 in my article on widows and orphans](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb43-1/tb133chernoff-widows.pdf#section.4).

> Space of each paragraph in the previous page will be increased when i use original command \widowpenaltiesand then it worded. Does this phenomenon indicate that when the widowpenalty occurs, I can reduce the line spacing of the previous page and squeeze the widow line into the previous page?

In general, you would need to do this manually. See [David Carlisle's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/670529/how-to-adjust-the-line-spacing-of-the-previous-page#comment1666736_670529).

> I'm working on an automatic mechanism for handling orphans and widows in my own defined documentclass.

I've written a package [`lua-widow-control`](https://ctan.org/pkg/lua-widow-control) that aims to do just that. It requires LuaLaTeX uses a different method to remove widows and orphans, but it is very effective at automatically removing widows and orphans.

Comment: My tex engine is xelatex, however thx for your answer :).

Comment: @Mahsatshak LuaLaTeX will compile most XeLaTeX documents without needing to make any changes to your document. The only real downside is that LuaLaTeX is usually a bit slower. There are a few minor incompatibilities, but nothing that is likely to cause you any real issues.

Comment: @Mahsatshak any particular reason for using xetex here? you would have _much_ more control from luatex.

Comment: Because my documentclass is very dependent on xeCjk, and the class has been maintained for many years, it is not easy to migrate to luatex